# How do I take an RBAC role and create an equivalent ACL in Azure?

Tags: azure, acl, rbac

Currently in order for a function app with a Blob trigger to work using managed identity, the function app needs to be given certain roles on the Storage Account.

According to the Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#grant-permission-to-the-identity
The following roles are necessary: Storage Blob Data Reader and Storage Queue Data Contributor.

After doing this, the function works perfectly fine and triggers when a blob is uploaded.
However, it has been suggested that we use ACL and remove the RBAC roles.

How do I map these RBAC roles to ACL mappings instead?

Comment: Out of curiosity, who suggested this, and for what reasons?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole The reasons are the production blob storage is used by many departments in a massive organisation, and they use ACL to restrict access to only the stuff on the storage account that is for you.

Comment: What exactly do they mean with ACL? An Access Control List has to do with networking, which is different from Role Based Access Controls. RBAC has to do with permissions. They are not the same thing. You might restrict access from a networking perspective, but that still doesn't take awway you need to give permissions. Also, a managed identity doesn't need to have any ACL. It is already coming from a trusted source. On top of that, you can't put a managed identity and regular users in the same bucket when it concerns networking.

Comment: @Marco What they mean by ACL is the Azure POSIX-like ACLs for managing Read, Write and Execute permissions for users and service principals, for a particular resource. In this case on storage accounts in particular: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control

Comment: I actually never knew that! But then mapping RBAC roles to ACL is not that difficult right? You would only have to determine if read, write or execute is required. And this page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model#permissions-table-combining-azure-rbac-and-acl gives you a very detailed table with examples for what ACL a role has. It comes down to you having to make a matrix of what functions require which access at which level/object of the storage account. I'd stick with RBAC roles, and suggest them to switch over to something ..

Comment: that requires less management overhead. Seems like a lot of work to me. Hence why RBAC roles make life easy.